# How to make my page non clickable when a form submit process is working?

Tags: jquery, forms, submit, overlay

I would like to load an overlay image or something when a long time form submit process is working. So that no one can click, any other links in the page during the process, and at the same time show a loading image over the overlay image...how can i make this work with jquery..

Answer (score 2):

Given the features you're after, check out [the blockUI plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/) for this, [you can find the demos here](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/#demos).